# Get value of Array object using Key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that contains two objects with Key Value Pairs.

```
Object 1 : Key: "FirstObj" Value: "xyz" 
Object 2 : Key: "SecondObj" Value: "abc"
```

I want to know how can I retrieve the value of array with Key `FirstObj`?

Tried this so far:

```
var getKeyValue= [];
 for(var i=0;i<myChartArray.length;i++)
 {
     getKeyValue.push(myChartArray[i]["FirstObj"]);

 }
```

Comment: You'll probably need a space between `var` and `i`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Could you add how you make `myChartArray`?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sc6jpjhm/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
let firstObj = myChartArray.find(item => item.Key === 'FirstObj');
console.log(firstObj.Value);
```

Note that this code uses ES6 features.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer of str, this is how you'd do it without ES6:

```
function getFirstObj(myChartArray){
    for(var i=0; i < myChartArray.length; i++){
       if (myChartArray[i].Key === 'FirstObj'){
           return myChartArray[i]
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use ES6 you could use `Array.prototype.filter()`.

The function would look something like this:

```
var yourValue = yourArray.filter(function(object) {

  return object.Key === 'FirstObj';

})[0].Value;
```

The variable `yourValue` will then contain the value you were looking for.

---

Alternatively if you just need to solve this particular case and you are not looking for an iterative, scalable solution. You can just select the object and value statically. This assumes you can be sure of the order of objects in your array. If the above is true for you, you can just do this:

`var value = youArray[0].Value;`

Comment: It's a nice solution which makes good sense in most cases, but beware that this will traverse the entire `Array`, instead of stopping after finding the value, which can be costly if the `Array` is very long.

Comment: True @LukaJacobowitz, but in the specific case mentioned above the cleanest and shortest solution available.

Comment: It's good to point out the caveats to using the given solution though :)

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using `filter()`

```js
var array = [];
array.push({Key:"FirstObj", Value:"xyz"});
array.push({Key:"SecondObj", Value:"abc"});


var found = array.filter(function(item) { return item.Key === "FirstObj"; });

console.log(found[0]);
```

Comment: It's a nice solution which makes good sense in most cases, but beware that this will traverse the entire `Array`, instead of stopping after finding the value, which can be costly if the `Array` is very long.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array#find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
var array = [{Key:"FirstObj", Value:"xyz"}, {Key:"SecondObj", Value:"abc"}],
    found = array.find(function(elem) { 
      return elem.Key === "FirstObj"; 
    });

console.log(found);
```